# Error connecting to database with SQLAlchemy and fastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have this setting on a fastAPI small application:

```
host_server = os.environ.get('host_server', 'localhost')
db_server_port = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('db_server_port', '5432')))
database_name = os.environ.get('database_name', 'mydatabasename123')
db_username = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('db_username', 'myusername123')))
db_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('db_password', 'mypassword123')))
ssl_mode = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('ssl_mode', 'prefer')))
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?sslmode={}'.format(db_username, db_password, host_server, db_server_port,
                                                               database_name, ssl_mode)

database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

locally it works, but when I try to deploy it to heroku, I change some things. I am use the DATABASE_URL env variable provided on Heroku:

```
DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://...'
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

or doing

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL, pool_size=3, max_overflow=0, echo=True
)
```

logs give me:

```
: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"postgres" is no longer accepted as a dialect name in SQLAlchemy.  The correct form is "postgresql", as you are using locally:

```py
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://...'
```

Using `'postgres://...'` raises

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'postgres//...'
```

This change was introduced in SQLAlchemy [1.4.0b1](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-3687655465c25a39b968b4f5f6e9170b)